# Linux utility program to write a matlab .mat file

Tags: linux, matlab

Consider the following text file `file`:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I would like to have linux command `writemat` that does the following:

```
$ writemat --size=3,3 --outputFile=m.mat --name=A <file
```

producing a matlab `.mat`  file `m.mat`, such that I can later do from within Matlab:

```
>> s=load('m.mat')

s = 

    A: [3x3 double]

>> s.A

ans =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
```

Does such a command exist? Or do I have to write my own using the `Matlab Application Programming interfaces`? However, the latter feels somewhat like reinventing the wheel..

Comment: Any reason for not parsing within Matlab via `textscan()` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want, but it may be equivalent: In Matlab you can load an ASCII file (like that in your example) using

```
load(name,'-ascii')
```

where `name` is a string containing the file name. The file contents are read into a Matlab variable with the same name as the file.

---

If you need several variables in the same file, you could write the ASCII file as

```
a=[
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9];
b=[
0 1 0 1];
```

(that is, add variable names and `[`, `]`, `;` signs), and then *run* it from Matlab.

Comment: Thanks, I did consider the `load` function.. But I think it is not suitable for my purpose.. I am actually looking for a way to put serveral arrays of different type into a single file..

Comment: Thanks, this was actually a new idea to me.. Seems to be a simple option that I have missed :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland Creating a .mat file would probably have the advantage of taking up less disk storage (I think the .mat format includes some compression). But this is definitely simpler :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes .mat files are compressed - but there is a 128 byte overhead, so very small arrays are better stored as ASCII or just binary. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf for a detailed description of the format.

Comment: @Floris Very interesting info!